# JSF adding hover to a panel

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, hover

*JSF-2.0, Mojarra 2.1.19, PrimeFaces 3.4.1*

I need hover event(mouseOver mouseOut) for a `p:panel` component. Let's imagine there is:

```
<h:form id="dataTableForm">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable>
        <p:panel id="hoverPanel">
            <p:commandLink id="button" value="Show" rendered="condition"></p:commandLink>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

My functional requirement tells, when the mouse pointer is on the `hoverPanel`, `p:commandLink` component needs to be displayed, otherwise(mouseOut) it needs to be hid. This can be done by setting it's CSS `display` property, I guess. I don't want to use `rendered` property of `p:commandLink` because it has already one and this shouldn't needs  going to server and coming back, it has to be done at client side.

I've tried to use:

```
$('.hoverPanel').hover(
   alert('mouseOn');           
);
```

But this didn't work also I need sth. more specific for each different `hoverPanel` components because of they're included in a `p:dataTable`.

Comment: You access a class but define an id that would also be altered by a naming container. Use a styleClass attribute instead.

Comment: @skuntsel I've a styleClass as named hoverPanel. But even if it works it doesn't provide my requirement, I don't need a thing which is applied for all hoverPanel components. As I said there are more than one panels in such cases because it's included in a datatable. So it should be applied to specific one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a wrong selector: you defined no class on your panel, but instead defined id that would be altered by the naming container. Taking into consideration your comment the easiest solution will be to define an additional class for a needed panel.

The view:

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="table">
        <p:panel id="hoverPanel" styleClass="base-class #{bean.condition ? 'change-panel' : ''}">
            <p:commandLink id="button" styleClass="btn" value="Show" rendered="condition">
            </p:commandLink>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

And do your job in JavaScript:

```
$('.change-panel').hover(
    function () {
       $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('visible');
    }
    //or do your job by binding two function handlers to distinguish between mouse events
);
```

### Full answer

As per your comments and given self-answer, which is obviously not the best way to do the job, I will post a complete answer. When you decide to ask next question, and will get an answer, try your best to fully investigate the code you have been presented. Also, it would be wise to learn some JavaScript/jQuery along the way.

The view shows a two-column datatable with the second column showing the panel with a link you want. The table contains all possible alternatives, so be sure to pick the best setup for you.

**View**:

```
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript name="js/js.js" target="body"/>
    <style>
        .invisible {
            display: none
        }
    </style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:dataTable value="#{bean.data}" var="data" id="table" rowIndexVar="index">
            <p:column headerText="Data">
                <h:outputText value="#{data}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Other functions">
                <p:panel id="hoverPanel" styleClass="#{((index eq 0) || (index eq 1) || (index eq 2)) ? 'change-panel' : ''}">
                    <h:outputText value="Row #{index + 1}"/>
                    <p:commandLink id="button" value="Show"
                                   rendered="#{!((index eq 1) || (index eq 3))}"
                                   styleClass="btn #{(index eq 0) ? 'invisible' : ''}"/>
                </p:panel>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.change-panel').hover(
        function () {
           $(this).find('.btn').toggleClass('invisible');
        }
    );
});
```

**Bean**:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class Bean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Q15435267Bean() {
        data.add("Data element 1");
        data.add("Data element 2");
        data.add("Data element 3");
        data.add("Data element 4");
        data.add("Data element 5");
    }

    public List<String> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

Comment: I couldn't associate `styleClass="base-class #{bean.condition ? 'change-panel' : ''}` with my code. Panel has already a class for example panelClass. How should I modify your styleClass value?

Comment: The idea behind this is that you assign *an extra* class to the panels you need upon some expression, that will act as a convenience identifier for your jQuery code. Basically, that class doesn't need to contain *any* CSS.

Comment: No. Sorry for my late answer I was at dinner. I inserted your code and wrote `$('.change-panel').hover(alert('2'));` and when the page loads it is alerting 2. But it's not working like commandLink has onmouseover or onmouseout event.

Comment: Also added  `styleClass="base-class #{bean.condition ? 'change-panel' : ''}` to panel and commandLink has `rendered="#{bean.condition}"`

Comment: Try the code literally. Note that I added CSS class to command link and visible class with the display property only. Do you make the binding in document.ready?

Comment: Added exactly upper code but commandLink is visible and not toggling I mean not hiding. What do you exactly mean with binding in document.ready? I have few other functions but I added your function purely like in your answer.

Comment: Should I lose my all hope?

Answer (score 0):

you first remove render on commandLink , as if condition is false link will be not exist on your html:

```
<h:form id="dataTableForm" prependId="false">
    <p:dataTable id="dataTable" rowIndexVar="index">
        <p:panel id="hoverPanel_#{index}">
            <p:commandLink id="button" value="Show" style="display: none;">             </p:commandLink>
        </p:panel>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

$("[id$='hoverPanel_1']").hover(
function(){
if'(#{put your condition where it was in render}'=='true'){
$("[id$='button']").show();
   alert('mouseOn');           
}
}, function(){
$("[id$='button']").hide();
```

});

Comment: You might not know it, but Primefaces' datatable is a naming container, so your approach won't work.

Comment: @skuntsel thank you for your annotation, i have modify my answer in jquery script to select ids which end with. i hope it work.

Comment: Unfortunately at this time your answer won't meet OP's requirements because he wouldn't like to attach JavaScript to *all* panels :)

Comment: @MohamedAli Consequence of overviewing your code, program passes directly first function which has the if condition even if it has true and executes hide function. And not alerting when mouse is on the panel.